# Is SSA form worth it if code generating to a high level language?

Tags: c, compiler, optimization, code-generation

I'm writing a compiler that compiles to C. This means that most of the time I piggyback on top of C for optimisations and generating code for multiple platforms.

Right now I can think of a few reasons why it might be beneficial:

- I can perform specific optimisations for my language
- It will be easier to translate the simplified [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) into C than it would be to handle all the edge cases in translating my semi-complex language to C
- It will make certain analysis on the code easier

I can think of a few drawbacks:

- The compiler is slower as I'll have to generate SSA [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation)

But is it worth it?

My main question is that **will C be able to optimise code translated from an SSA IR well or better**?

I imagine that the code the SSA form translates to will have labels and jumps everywhere. It wont use C constructs like for loops or if statements, etc. Will C find this easier or harder to optimise?

I'm keen on doing this purely to learn more about the SSA form, as well as if I eventually generate code for [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), it will be a bit easier.

Bonus question: is there a different IR I can look into that may be more suited to the problem at hand?

Comment: You need to define your terms.  What is SSA?  Social Security Administration?  What is IR?  Infrared?  Don't just assume that people know what you're talking about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good point. But if they don't know what I'm talking about then I'm not sure if they are the audience I have in mind for my question.

Comment: Kinda thought you'd say that.  Keep in mind that this is a website that is supposed to have broad applicability; questions and answers should be useful to others, not just to the chosen few.  Also, note that we don't necessarily have to be PhD's in the subject matter to help you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You have a valid point here, in general, but in this specific case he's right.  Compiler work can be very specialized.  Heck, I maintain a production-grade compiler and I do understand the terms being used here, and I'm *still* not qualified to answer this question, because it doesn't use SSA or a LLVM-style codegen, so it's outside of my realm of experience.

Comment: Indeed. I think for most questions you can maybe generalise them to help others, but this is just an outlier I suppose. I can't imagine if this gets answered it would help too many people.

Comment: For a question with such precise terms, the question itself seems awfully general.  What do you mean by "better?"  If this is a performance question, the only way to know for sure is to measure.

Comment: In any case, I don't think specialized knowledge is necessarily needed here.  Not all of us know what IR means at first blush, but those of us who have done a minimal study of compilers know what an **expression tree** is, which is a form of IR.  The description of SSA at Wikipedia is strongly suggestive of **immutable design,** which doesn't require a compiler expert to understand either. *("each variable is assigned exactly once, and every variable is defined before it is used. Existing variables in the original IR are split into versions")*

Comment: lol classifying C as a high level language

Comment: Finally, the success with which any given C compiler will be able to optimize the resulting C code will depend, to a greater or lesser extent, on how well said C code manages to respect and follow C's natural idioms.  If it's a poor match, you may not get decent optimizations.  You may get better results by making your compile target LLVM IR, rather than C.

Comment: I think this is an interesting and answerable question. SSA is a pretty well-known concept if you're into compilers. This question is high-level enough that it can be answered by lay persons such as me, without having to resort to overly much speculation. (Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to write an answer, but I will revisit the question within the next couple of days.) Closing this question because SSA isn't well-known to the wider developer community would be a mistake; by the same logic I should close .NET-related questions of which I know nothing.

Comment: @amon: I voted to close when those terms were not defined in the question.  I have retracted my close vote now that they are.

Comment: I think the performance will depend very much on the specific C compilers and the specific details of how you translate the code to C.  Personally, simplifying analysis,simplifying code generation (to C), and easing the way for other back-ends, particularly LLVM, would significantly outweigh any concerns I had about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat difficult to answer this definitively without knowing more about the language you are writing. However, it's probably helpful to think about what kind of code transformations you're expecting to perform between the type checking and the code gen. If you're planning some optimisation passes or some form of sophisticated memory or lock analysis, then it may well be worth it.

By the same token it's hard to say whether an intermediate representation would help or hinder the C optimisations. It's probably fair to say that if you use a low level IR, like LLVM's, you may well lose type information which in turn could limit the analyses the C compiler can work with.

For inspiration I would recommend you look at the recent work on [Rust's MIR](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/04/19/MIR.html) or [Swift's SIL](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst) which are both high level IRs that retain type information. Interestingly they both lower to LLVM's IR for optimisation and code gen. The discussions cover the performance cost, and both went through the expense of re-factoring to include the high level IR. They had different reasons for the inclusion but both, effectively, include sophisticated analysis passes that they considered justified the cost. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 1):

On the optimisations side of your question, the answer is no. The C compiler's optimisations won't be targetted at C code that looks like SSA. It will be targetted at code that looks like C code.

Furthermore, the SSA form can express things at a level that C cannot; LLVM IR can express more than C. It can have invariants (or variants) that C can't - for instance, different aliasing rules.

At absolute *best*, the C compiler will optimize equally well as the LLVM compiler.

Comment: I think the first part of this answer is a little un-necessary and not particularly constructive.

Comment: @flooblebit: I removed the obnoxious parts.

Comment: None of this is that simple, and certainly in the context of IRs, C is a high-level language.  A C compiler given "SSAed" input can still potentially output better code *even if it does use LLVM for code generation*.  If it doesn't use an LLVM back-end, there's even less of a reason to think it would be inferior to directly targeting LLVM performance-wise. Most compilers can handle non-idiomatic code quite well because they tend to produce it themselves during optimizations, and either way this assumes that the "non-SSA" output is idiomatic which is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like SSA is an extra step in your case, and I wonder if you've considered whether the possible optimization is worth worrying about.

Will your language sometimes be used to write functions/procedures that will do heavy computation *that doesn't call lower-level functions*?
If so, then compiler-level optimization is a valid concern.

I only ask because sometimes people are concerned about optimization in code where the instruction pointer seldom is, because it's in lower-level functions, or because it isn't called that often.